# Preparing a server for mysql replication and use it as standalone

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication, redundancy

I want to host an application on a single server running `MySQL` server. To get the best performance I plan on using a `UNIX` socket connection (to avoid `TCP` overhead). Later, I would like to scale up by adding extra servers which would be `MySQL` read-only instances (`slave`) replicated from the first server (`master`). What I'm interested in is coming up with an initial design that allows me to scale up easily and smoothly to the replication setup in a later phase, and I have a few questions regarding this:

**Q1: Is it recommended NOT to use a same server via a `UNIX` socket while doing replication to other servers over `TCP`?**

**Q2: Is there a performance impact (if so what is the order of magnitude) to setting up a `MySQL` server for replication as a master but not use the replication?**

Comment: Did you get your question answered?

Comment: First thanks for your answer. It seems that Q2 was addressed but not Q1. If you know some online resources you can share that support your answer that would be great as it would give me and future readers more material for analysis, as right now it very much feels like you're just stating your opinion without explaining why and some might be tempted to ignore your answer (although you may be right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a large impact when a server is setup for replication due to the logging to the binary log files. If replication isn't being used then it would certainly be counter-intuitive to incur those performance penalties while not gaining the benefits. Although the logs would be useful for recovery purposes should your database server crash prior to the replication being put into effect.

Setting up for replication is a relatively easy task and you can hold-off on doing so until you actually need it.